# ListBox Groupstyle display: How to design a group name?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I want to group my items (images) in a ListBox by the date it was created. Then I just use this code:

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle />
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

**BUT** When I tried to apply some style(i.e Border), I got NO group name displayed. ONLY the **Border**
Here  my new implementation of the groupings using DateTime:

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateCreated}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

Here is my ICollectionView in my MainWindow:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CollectedFiles);
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("DateCreated", new DateTimeToDateConverter()));
        view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("FileFullName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

**NOTE:** I use DateTimeToDateConverter() converter which returns date without time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupstyle.headertemplate.aspx

> When you define groups using the [GroupDescriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.groupdescriptions.aspx), your view object
>   (a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) object or an object that derives from
>   [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx)) wraps each group in a CollectionViewGroup object.

Basically, when you add a `PropertyGroupDescription` WPF actually generates a [`CollectionViewGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.aspx). You'll need to bind to the [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.name.aspx) property, not the DateCreated property (which doesn't exist on the new CollectionViewGroup the WPF engine created for you).

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                  </Border>
              </DataTemplate>
          </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
     </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Wow..great.. really miss that one.. Thanks a lot..now its displaying.